# Parsing temporary table into another in SQL, keeping the column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have a temporary table which looks something like this.

```
| USER_NO | MY_CODE1      | MY_CODE2      |  
| UserNo1 | UserNo1_Code1 | UserNo1_Code2 |  
| UserNo2 | UserNo2_Code1 | UserNo2_Code2 |
```

Where the first line is column names, the 2nd and 3rd are values. I need to append these records into another table.

```
| CusRef  | CodeName | CodeValue     |  
| UserNo1 | MY_CODE1 | UserNo1_Code1 |  
| UserNo2 | MY_CODE2 | UserNo1_Code2 |  
| UserNo2 | MY_CODE1 | UserNo2_Code1 |  
| UserNo2 | MY_CODE2 | UserNo2_Code2 |
```

There a number of other fields in that other table which I need to reference from other table but that is another issue.

What SQL could I use to make this first bit work?

Answer (score 1):

Your desired results can be obtained with `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT USER_NO As CusRef,
       CodeName,
       CodeValue     
FROM #YourTempTable
UNPIVOT (CodeValue FOR CodeName IN (MY_CODE1, MY_CODE2)) AS U
```